# Во скольких вкладках открыт сайт?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Как проверить, во скольких вкладках открыт сайт? Чтобы можно было избежать высокой нагрузки на сервер, если например на сайте каждые пару секунд идут несколько запросов на сервер. Скажем у человека открыто 10 вкладок, но пользуется только 1. А в итоге еще 9 отправляют 5 запросов на сервер каждые 2 секунды, хотя толку от этого нет.

Comment: Use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), Luke!

Comment: А как? Есть точные события открытия, закрытия вкладок? А если закрыли браузер или электричество обрубили. Это как раз интересует.

Comment: ну, поэтому я не стал писать ответ) события открытия и закрытия есть, и при закрытии браузера тоже вроде срабатывают, но вот насчет обрубили электричество тут не ясно что делать. [window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload) , [window.unload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onunload)

Comment: А не лучше будет проверять, активна ли текущая вкладка, и если нет, то просто не посылать запросы?

Comment: Как раз так и хочу.

Comment: В смысле вычислять активность? Движения мыши, клавиатуру?

Comment: Page Visibility API https://stackoverflow.com/a/12186061/4854931

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из комментариев нашел наиболее правильное решение для моей задачи.

Использование
[Page Visibility API](https://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/)

`document.hidden`

Если вкладка видна, то следует выполнять обновление страницы, если не видна то нет смысла в обновлении. Количество вкладок значение не имеет. 
Это подходит для онлайн редактора, когда нужно регулярно проверять не изменил ли кто нибудь документ который ты сейчас редактируешь, но важно не посылать по 20 запросов с 20 открытых вкладок.

Решения на базе onfocus и onblur имеют много недостатков. Один из них это например работа с 2 мониторами, мы открыли вкладку, переключились в другое окно, но всё еще видим нашу вкладку, однако потеряв фокус она перестала обновляться, хотя всё еще видна, и не факт что содержит самые последние сведения. Если надо и видимую вкладку замораживать, то тут уже придется вешать разные события, чтобы  точно убедиться в "активности" пользователя.

Answer (score 1):

В современных браузерах неактивные вкладки способны практически замораживаться. Например, в хроме прекращается обработка таймеров, прекращается requestAnimationFrame.

Если отвечать в общем на вопрос, проверьте для начала какой нибудь статистикой какой процент аудитории открывает несколько вкладок, иначе все дальнейшие оптимизации будут крайне несущественными.

Comment: Ну я вижу у себя на сервере что количество запросов увеличивается сильно когда вкладок много открыто.

Comment: @manking Вот когда я экспериментировал с D3 и таймерами, я обернул код опроса сервера в библиотеке d3-timer, при уходе с вкладки запросы прекращались, это видно даже по devtools.

Answer (score 1):

Некогда делали так. Ставим интервал, каждый раз увеличивая счетчик. Если счетчик достиг определенного значения, запросы на сервер не отправляем. Если на странице происходят какие-то шевеления (события ниже), то счетчик обнуляем, если нужно, запускаем отправку запросов по новой.

window.onscroll - прокрутка страницы

window.onmousemove - движение мыши

window.onfocus - переход во вкладку

window.onkeydown - нажатие клавиш

window.onclick - нажатие на кнопки мыши

Можно сделать проще и следить только за onfocus/onblur.

Но если пользователь ждет какого-то события с сайта и решил во время ожидания посмотреть что-то иное, открыв рядом второе окно, то от сайта он ничего не дождется.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9502074/revisions

Comment: Подобное в стиме используют. Довольно криво.